# Looking for regex to obfuscate email to t*@w***.de

Tags: php, regex

I have the following:

```
$pattern     = "/^([\w_]{1})(.+)([\w_]{1}@)/u";
$replacement = "$1*$3***$4";
$email       = "testa@weste.de";
echo "obfuscated: ".preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $email).RT;
```

The result is: `t*a@***weste.de`
But I would like to have: `t*@w***.de`
How to grab the letter after the @ and not before. And how does it work with the .de part?

Comment: I personally like regex but IMHO I think using regex for this problems is a overkill when you can clearly just split your email by `@` and `.` and just obfuscate anything between.

Comment: @YaMiN The only problem to your solution is that you can have subdomains too, non only top domains (ex: john@lab.foo.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the replacement in the example data, you might use a match with `\K` to forget what is matched after the first character and keep it.

To keep the first character after the @ sign, you can use a capture group and use that in the replacement.

```
^\w\K[^\s@]+@(\w)[^\s.@]+
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\w` Match a single word char (That will also match `_`)
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[^\s@]+` Match 1+ chars other than `@` or a whitespace char
- `@` Match the @ char
- `(\w)` Capture **group 1**, match a word char (to keep)
- `[^\s.@]+` Match 1+ chars other than `@`, a whitespace char or dot

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WePdih/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/gvGLp)

In the replacement use a single capture group `*@$1***`

```
$email = "testa@weste.de";
$pattern = "/^\w\K[^\s@]+@(\w)[^\s.@]+/";
$replacement = "*@$1***";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $email);
```

Output

```
t*@w***.de
```

---

You can make the pattern as specific as you would like. If there should for example be a dot followed by at least 2 chars a-z at the end of the string, and you don't want to stop matching at the first dot after the @

```
^\w\K[^\s@]+@(\w)[^\s@]+(?=\.[a-z]{2,}$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uy8ned/1)

Comment: You are a genius. thx.
I modified it a bit to /^\w{2}\K[^\s@]+@(\w{3})[^\s.@]+/
Another nice try would be to get one asterix for any given character.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to do it:

```
$email = 'someemail@domain.com'
[$firstPart, $lastPart] = explode('@', $email);
$maskedEmail = str_replace(substr($firstPart, 0, 7), str_repeat('*', 7), $email);
```

Uses PHP native functions and works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and tried to use the REGEX but (as @hamburger mentioned in a comment) I needed to keep the asterisks so here was my solution:

```php
function asterisk($str,$keep_char = 2, $c='*'){
    return substr($str, 0, $keep_char).str_repeat($c, strlen($str) - $keep_char);
}

function hide($email){
    $user = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));    
    $user = asterisk($user);

    $domain = substr($email, strpos($email, '@')  + 1);
    $tld = substr($domain, strrpos($domain, '.') + 1);

    $domain = asterisk($domain);

    return sprintf('%s@%s.%s', $user, $domain, $tld);
}
```